# Migrating an app from PHP 5.2 to 5.5

Tags: php, php-5.2, php-5.6

I have an app currently running on a PHP 5.2 server that I need to migrate to a PHP 5.5 (or 5.6) server. What are the things to look at, what issues might I encounter?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Many things I'm sure. One of which and if you're using MySQL db *by any chance*, would require to switch/convert all `mysql_` to `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: I would start with [the 5.5 migration guide](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.php) and work back from there. I would also say that you should consider jumping to 5.6 instead of 5.5 (why jump into something less than the latest version?)

Comment: Employing a checker tool should be among things to do. Just search "php version compatibility check" and see several results. I've never used any of them though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is well documented.

- http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php

Go through each of these one by one.  This may be a good time to refactor your application.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you have to migrate your code from 5.2 to 5.3, then to 5.4, then to 5.5, and then to 5.6. For each Migration, the PHP documentation has listed what you may encounter:

- 5.2 -> 5.3 : http://php.net/manual/de/migration53.php
- 5.3 -> 5.4 : http://php.net/manual/de/migration54.php
- 5.4 -> 5.5 : http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.php
- 5.5 -> 5.6 : http://php.net/manual/de/migration56.php

Look for Backward incompatible changes and deprecated features. Hope I could help.